# Lemon Butter Sauce too acidic

Tags: sauce, lemon, scallops

My Lemon Butter sauce was way too acidic. What can I use to mellow the sauce? I started with 1/4 cup lemon, added shallots and garlic and reduced by half. Then added 1/2 stick butter, cherry tomatoes and fresh bay scallops, and served over angle hair pasta. It was very lemony and acidic.

Comment: It doesn't help after the fact -- but consider using less juice, but include the zest (either grated or finely chopped, or large pieces to remove before serving).

Answer (score 4):

If that is 1/4 cup lemon juice, that seems like quite a lot and reducing it is also probably making it taste even more lemony. If you want to keep about the same amount of liquid, try softening the shallots and garlic in 1 t olive oil and then adding 2T dry white wine and reducing. Add 1T lemon juice and bring to boil again but don't reduce, add in the cherry tomatoes, scallops and the 1/2 stick butter. You could also reserve half the butter to swirl in after the scallops are cooked through.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to achieve (decreasing the acidic taste or increasing the pH) it could be as simple as adding a dash of honey or baking soda respectively...

Answer (score 0):

I did both, added a touch baking soda and honey, cut the whole sauce in half, added broth and water and finally added capers and butter as originally planned.

Worked well